# Binding raw socket to address with TCP protocol kills process

Tags: windows, sockets, rust, raw-sockets

Using the `socket2` lib https://crates.io/crates/socket2 simply binding to an address with a raw socket using TCP kills the process. If I create a socket and simply try to send over it I get an os error `An invalid argument was supplied. (os error 10022)`

Assuming this is not a crate issue but instead a windows issue, whats its cause?

```
use socket2::{Domain, Protocol, SockAddr, Socket, Type};
use std::{env, net::SocketAddr, process::{Command, Stdio}, thread, time::Duration, io::{BufReader, BufRead}};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
    args.remove(0);

    if args.len() == 0 {
        let file_path = env::current_exe().unwrap();

        let file_path = file_path.to_str().unwrap();

        let (command, cmd_args) = (
            "powershell.exe",
            vec![
                String::from("-NoProfile"),
                String::from("-NoExit"),
                String::from("-Command"),
                String::from("Start-Process"),
                String::from(file_path),
                String::from("-Verb"),
                String::from("RunAs"),
                String::from("-ArgumentList"),
                String::from("'bind'"),
            ],
        );

        let mut cmd = Command::new(command)
            .args(cmd_args)
            .stderr(Stdio::piped())
            .spawn()
            .unwrap();

        let err = cmd.stderr.take().unwrap();
        let reader = BufReader::new(err);

        for line in reader.lines() {
            println!("{}", line.unwrap());
        }

        println!("DONE");
    } else {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));

        let address = SockAddr::from(SocketAddr::new([0, 0, 0, 0].into(), 0));

        let send_socket = Socket::new(Domain::IPV4, Type::RAW, Some(Protocol::TCP))?;

        send_socket.bind(&address)?;

        loop {}
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: port zero? that doesn't feel right

Comment: @Toerktumlare Generally speaking yes. By binding to port 0 the OS will provide you a random unbound / open port. However, even if you select a port... it still fails.

Comment: The other issue on socket2 needed "checksum". Don't know what that means (maybe you can't use raw for TCP?). Looks like 0.0.0.0:0 is correct though. https://github.com/rust-lang/socket2/issues/388#issuecomment-1426573615

Comment: MS also says you can't bind a raw TCP socket on WinXP to Win7 (seems like it's just old and it applies from XP onward) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN#limitations-on-raw-sockets

Comment: @drewtato how can I send a syn packet? I dont need to connect. Im building a traceroute app with TCP and UDP... using raw sockets in linux and macos... not Win...